# Quick search ViewPart

Tags: eclipse-plugin

In my Eclipse plugin I'm displaying data in own view using `TableViewer`. I've added search functionality for this view via custom dialog being showed after pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>. To do it I've used key listener attached to `TableViewer`'s Table. In Windows, search works fine but in Linux it is being overridden by other functionality: Eclipse displays a text field at the bottom of the active view and does incremental search.

I want my plugin to behave the same on both platforms (I haven't decided yet which approach will be more convenient).

- how to enable / modify this functionality in Windows?
- how to disable it in Linux?

Comment: it seems that this search box is part of system, so it won't be available in windows. Now, the only problem, is to find it in SWT and disable.

Comment: my bad guy is OS.gtk_tree_view_set_search_column